# After joining meshes armature ignores new (second) mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, transforms, weight-painting

[image]First question for this beginner. Slowly kinda understanding some of it but I have a long way to go. I may be using the wrong terms so your patience is appreciated.
I am using blender to create things to 3D prints so my end goal is to add clothing/gear to characters, pose them however I want and export into stl and print.

Anyways, here goes:

I have a rigged character I am trying to clothe. I pose my character to be inside the clothes and merge with Ctrl+J (tried boolean tool but most of the cloth disappears). After Ctrl+J the clothes do not move with the character.
I thank you in advance for your help.
Tim

Comment: Hello could you please show some pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you parented your character to the rig so that you could pose it, it created a set of vertex groups, one for each bone.  (Either you used 'with automatic weights'; or 'with empty groups' and then weight painting)  Joining the clothes to the character does not add the clothes vertices to those vertex groups.

The vertex groups are what tell Blender what part of the character mesh to move when you move a deforming bone.  You need to use weight painting or some other tools to add the vertices from the clothes to the vertex groups that match the bone you want to use to move the clothes.

You might be able to undo your parenting and redo it with the new mesh, but you'll probably be better off learning and using weight painting.

Comment: Guess I have to learn weight painting then. Thanks for taking the time to explain that MF, I do appreciate it.